# What are the key points for using LINQ pagination and stored procedure pagination?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures, pagination

I have a question about LINQ pagination and stored procedure pagination:

1. If I am using LINQ pagination, then what logic use Microsoft? Means it load all data into list and then performed pagination logic?

   For example, if I have 1 million records in a SQL Server database and I want to use LINQ pagination then how will it work?

   Code snippet:

   ```
   _list = _list.Skip(StartIndex).Take(FetchRecords).ToList();
   ```
2. If LINQ loads all records first, then do I have to go for stored procedure pagination?

Comment: It depends on how cleverly you use LINQ .... if you do a `.ToList()` on your query before using `.Skip()` and `.Take()` - then yes, EF will load the whole set of data into memory. But that's just because you've told it so. If you operate with an `IQueryable<T>` and apply Skip/Take, then EF will use whatever server-based mechanisms for pagination that SQL Server offers and will **only** return those rows you've requested with the `.Take(n)` operator

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember that

The **ToList**(IEnumerable) method forces immediate query evaluation and returns a List that contains the query results.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist

ie without ToList method call, query is not executed hence no data.

Secondly you should also use OrderBy method eg.  `OrderBy(o => o.ID);` as you should explicitly know in which order items are skipped and taken.

Further consider using 'where' and 'select' method to limit the data payload.